# How to mimic "Save As" of a webpage to get its source code?

Tags: html, curl, web-scraping, wget

I'm trying to download the source code of a webpage.

When I tried "View Page Source", the portion of the webpage that I'm interested in is not in it. It seems to be "hidden" in

```
<div class="row5" info_abc></div>
```

and the actual text/formating is not there.

If I do a "Save As", I get everything, including the portion of the page that I want. The code also looks a bit different:

```
<div info_abc="" class="row5">...
```

I can also see this code if I do the "Inspect Element" using Chrome.

How can I get the full source code of this webpage (not including other parts of the website), like what I can get when I "Save" the webpage? Can I do it using `curl` or `wget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` and `wget` would proably not work. Pages like this are usually loaded dynamically using javascript. One way around that is to use Selenium (or its competitors) to emulate browser behavior. [There are tons of postings about this, for example here.](https://bitbar.com/blog/what-is-and-why-do-we-need-selenium-framework/)

I haven't personally tried it, but I've recently run into [Shellnium: Simple Selnium WebDriver for Bash](https://dev.to/rasukarusan/shellnium-simple-selnium-webdriver-for-bash-1a9k) which you may want to take a look into.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, curl and wget didn't work. I've had some success after trying Selenium with Chrome driver, but the Bash one looks interesting.